# Why is IIS Worker Process eating memory on windows server 2008 (vs windows server 2003)

Tags: .net, windows, windows-server-2008

My .Net 4 web app was running on windows server 2003 38 bit.

I've just upgraded to a new server with windows server 2008 64 bit.

I still got both servers running the same web app,

On windows server 2003 the app takes 55k RAM

And on windows server 2008 it takes 285K RAM

Same application, didn't change a thing and there are still no users at the new server.

What am I missing? Can the same application take a lot more memory on windows 2008?

Thanks

Rafael

Answer (score 1):

You might say "Windows Server takes 5 times as much RAM.  OMG!!!!"

I prefer to say "Windows Server just uses 200K more initial space.  Who cares?"

The important thing is to see how the application scales under load.

I suspect the difference with several concurrent users will be relatively small.  I'm guessing that, ultimately, Server 2008 will scale *better*.

But the only way to be sure is to *test* it.

IMHO...

Comment: I care :) the same application with load (not heavy) didn't get to 200K on the old server. I really hope it scales better....

Answer (score 1):

When the application starts up it reserves memory. If more memory is available it will reserve more.

Also 64bit applications use more space than 32bit application.